# calculate double sum

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics, probability-distributions, summation

I have the following.

$\sum_{x=1}^n \sum_{i = 1}^x \frac{2}{n(n+1)}$

Hint from Milton book first $n$ integers have the sum $\frac{(n+1)n}{2}$

This is for verifiying that it it's a valid joint distrubution.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Check that you have written it correctly.  As it currently stands, the summands are constants with respect to the index of the summations and so can be factored outside...  $\sum\limits_{x=1}^n\sum\limits_{i=1}^x\frac{2}{n(n+1)}=\frac{2}{n(n+1)}\sum\limits_{x=1}^n\sum\limits_{i=1}^x1$

Comment: I feel so stupid now, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that no summand depends on sum variables $i$ and $x$. Therefore
$$\sum_{x = 1}^n\sum_{i = 1}^x \frac{2}{n(n + 1)} = \frac{2}{n(n + 1)}\sum_{x = 1}^n\sum_{i = 1}^x 1 = \frac{2}{n(n + 1)}\sum_{x = 1}^n x = \frac{2}{n(n + 1)} \frac{n(n + 1)}{2} = 1.$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
\sum_{x=1}^n \sum_{i = 1}^x \frac{2}{n(n+1)}
=\sum_{x=1}^n\frac{2x}{n(n+1)}
=\frac{2}{n(n+1)}\sum_{x=1}^n x
=\frac{2}{n(n+1)}\frac{n(n+1)}{2}
=1.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Since the summation term does not depend on $i$ we can simplify the double sum to just one sum: $$\sum\limits_{x=1}^n \sum\limits_{i=1}^x \frac{2}{n(n+1)}=\sum\limits_{x=1}^n \frac{2x}{n(n+1)}$$
Using the hint from your book we get:
$$\begin{split}
\sum\limits_{x=1}^n \frac{2x}{n(n+1)}&=\sum\limits_{x=1}^n \frac{x}{1+2+...+n} \\  &=\frac{1}{1+2+...+n}+\frac{2}{1+2+...+n}+...+\frac{n}{1+2+...+n}=\frac{1+2+...+n}{1+2+...+n}=1
\end{split}$$